# What type of writing pen is suited for travelling?

Tags: gear

I like carrying a notepad and a pen wherever I go. However, the ones I've used so far are either:

1. hard to write with - the ink won't hit the paper
2. leak ink after a month or so - maybe because of temperature or
   pressure changes

Can someone recommend a pen that's easy to write with and isn't prone to leakage?

Comment: Do you mean pens to use during flight?

Comment: I always stock up on fine ballpoint pens when I'm in Japan. They are abundant there and hard to find and expensive at home (Australia). They seem to be much less prone to leaking to, I assume due to capillary action in the thinner ink reservoir.

Comment: This question reminds me a story when US launched their space program. They wanted a pen able to write even without gravity. They spent a lot of money and found a new technology for writing in extreme conditions. Soviets at the same time had the same problem, but not that much money. They came up with a simple pencil.

Comment: @mouviciel That's an [urban legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Pen#Uses_in_the_U.S._and_Russian_space_programs).

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee yup, flight included. I did think of pencils, but I find they're not great to travel with - the lead smears on clothes and documents

Comment: if you don't like a regular pencil, a mechanical pencil might be better?

Comment: I've had really bad luck with mechanical pencils in the past - lead breakage and so forth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of the Fisher Space Pen. I've got a couple of the Bullets (400 model). They're compact when they're closed, they write upside down. Outside of the fear of permanently misplacing one, I can't say that I've ever had a complaint.

Comment: The famous alternative is a pencil ;)

Comment: Just wanted to add that I recently got this pen - and it works as well as advertised. The ink always hits paper and never smears; it even wrote on wet surfaces ! My only fear now is having to get a refill =) thanks again !